# Positioning or margin problem in a0poster.cls

Tags: positioning, margins, a0poster

I‘d like to build a template for posters with a0poster.cls (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/a0poster) and started setting up the background.

Why are the positioning commands not working properly? Everything has a shift to the left and down. Is there something in the class code that causes this?

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) (logo) {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)  {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[below= 6cm of current page.north, anchor=north, minimum width=83.1cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=red] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the result you get? To me it looks like expected.

Comment: Did you compile two times? I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY3fG.png from your code

Comment: Yes, I did. I now replaced the files with the ones from ctan and the result is as expected. Maybe an old version. No idea. But thank you for pointing me to the solution

Comment: You're welcome!